# How to send OpenAI stream response from Nextjs API to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, openai-api

I tried [openai-streams](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openai-streams) + [nextjs-openai](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-openai), they only works for Node 18+, however, they failed on Node 17 and lower. I'm restricted to Node 17 and lower as Digital Oceans App Platform currently not supporting Node 18.

I also tried [this method](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/issues/18#issuecomment-1369996933) which works well on client side, but it exposes the API key. I want to implement within the NextJS API route, but I'm unable to pass the streaming response to the client.

With the code below, I can only get the first chunk of response from the API route, and not able to get the streaming response to have the ChatGPT effect. Please kindly help.

```js
// /api/prompt.js

import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";
import { Readable } from "readable-stream";

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const completion = await openai.createCompletion(
    {
      model: "text-davinci-003",
      prompt: "tell me a story",
      max_tokens: 500,
      stream: true,
    },
    { responseType: "stream" }
  );

  completion.data.on("data", async (data) => {
    const lines = data
      .toString()
      .split("\n")
      .filter((line) => line.trim() !== "");

    for (const line of lines) {
      const message = line.replace(/^data: /, "");
      if (message === "[DONE]") {
        return;
      }
      try {
        const parsed = JSON.parse(message);
        const string = parsed.choices[0].text;
        Readable.from(string).pipe(res);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Could not JSON parse stream message", message, error);
      }
    }
  });
```

```js
// /components/Completion.js

export default function Completion() {
  const [text, setText] = useState();

  const generate = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/api/prompt");
    console.log("response: ", response);
    const text = await response.text();
    console.log("text: ", text);
    setText((state) => state + text);
  };
  
  // ... rest
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `openai-streams/node` entrypoint on Node <18, which will return a Node.js `Readable` instead of a WHATWG `ReadableStream`. I'll update the docs to be clearer soon.

---

### [Node: Consuming streams in Next.js API Route](https://github.com/SpellcraftAI/openai-streams#node-consuming-streams-in-nextjs-api-route-node)

If you cannot use an Edge runtime or want to consume Node.js streams for another reason, use `openai-streams/node`:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { OpenAI } from "openai-streams/node";

export default async function test(_: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const stream = await OpenAI("completions", {
    model: "text-davinci-003",
    prompt: "Write a happy sentence.\n\n",
    max_tokens: 25,
  });

  stream.pipe(res);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use `StreamingTextResponse`
of `vercel AI sdk`

Attached is some [example code form their docs](https://sdk.vercel.ai/docs/getting-started#create-an-api-route)

```
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from 'openai-edge'
import { OpenAIStream, StreamingTextResponse } from 'ai'

const config = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY
})
const openai = new OpenAIApi(config)

export const runtime = 'edge'

export async function POST(req) {
  const { messages } = await req.json()
  const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
    model: 'gpt-4',
    stream: true,
    messages
  })
  const stream = OpenAIStream(response)
  return new StreamingTextResponse(stream)
}
```

Notes:

1. This requires the [Edge Runtime](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/edge-functions/edge-runtime)
2. The library `openai-edge` [requires Node 18+](https://github.com/dan-kwiat/openai-edge/blob/main/package.json#L25). However, this is expected to be deprecated soon with the support for streaming in the official `openai` library.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is it possible to modify the data within this stream? E.g. I wish to return an object with the content (`data.choices[0].message?.content`) and a custom field. My understanding is that due to the fact that `OpenAiStream` formats the response, this is not possible and you need to build a custom stream.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use openai-edge or others, should keep use an official packages/modules

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses the latest nextJS (uses the nextJS `app` router, not  the older `pages` router), and **without any extra libraries.**

*Its the complete code, with comments to help you to customize it to your needs.*

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type OpenAI from 'openai';

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const oaiResponse = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    // ...
    stream: true,
  })

  // ...
  const encoder = new TextEncoder()

  async function* makeIterator() {
    // first send the OAI chunks
    for await (const chunk of oaiResponse) {
      const delta = chunk.choices[0].delta.content as string
      // you can do any additional post processing / transformation step here, like
      completeMessage += delta

      // you can yield any string by `yield encoder.encode(str)`, including JSON:
      yield encoder.encode(JSON.stringify({ assistant_response_chunk: delta }))
    }

     // optionally, some additional info can be sent here, like
     yield encoder.encode(JSON.stringify({ thread_id: thread._id }))
  }

  return new Response(iteratorToStream(makeIterator()))
}


function iteratorToStream(iterator: any) {
  return new ReadableStream({
    async pull(controller) {
      const { value, done } = await iterator.next()

      if (done) {
        controller.close()
      } else {
        controller.enqueue(value)
      }
    },
  })
}
```

This solution was mainly inspired from the [NextJS' steaming response](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#streaming), using the web APIs directly.

Comment: I have been very confused by the line `await openai.chat.completions.create`. Is it awaiting a response from OpenAI API? It's not clear to me whether our stream to the end client starts once we have the whole response from OpenAI servers, or are we sending chunks as soon as we have the first chunk of data from OpenAI? Perhaps you can clarify this doubt @vedant-agarwala, thank you!

Comment: @josealvarez97 That lines means the HTTP request has succeeded, and the (streaming) response has been created!